Communicating from CD to CM
I was thinking and not able to figure out a few things. I also checked the official documentation and the blogs but could not figure out one thing.

Sitecore CD do not have connection strings for Web and Core databases.
We have events like publish:end:remote

Question:
How does the CM instance know when a particular event (e.g., publish:end:remote) is triggered on a CD instance, and how do the actions subscribed to this event execute?
Specifically, how does this communication between CM and CD work? Where are the details about the event stored so that the CM instance is aware of it?
I am interested in understanding how this functions in both architectures:

PaaS hosting
On-prem hosting


A CD instances must have connection strings for the Web db. If it doesn't it will not work.

The communication is handled via whichever event queue is configured for the publishing target.
If you publish an item, look in the following event queues and you will see similar to below:
CORE DB (this is defaultEventQueue)

Sitecore.Publishing.StartPublishingRemoteEvent
Sitecore.Publishing.PublishStatusUpdatedRemoteEvent
Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishCompletedRemoteEvent

CD WEB DB (this queue is shared between CM and CD)

Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent

Using the event queue of the CD publishing target, the CM can be made aware of events completing.

In order to communicate to CM environment from CD environment, this can be done with the help of remote events.

You can raise the remote events from Content Delivery server and this will be added to event queue using below code snippet.

var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(database);
var eventQueue = database.RemoteEvents.EventQueue;
eventQueue.QueueEvent<MyEventRemote>(new MyEventRemote());

This will add event details to the EventQueue table in the web database as by default on Content Delivery environment default event queue is web.

CM environment then needs to subscribes/listen to the remove events in the queue and executes the necessary action. Below is the code snippet to subscribe to the remote event. It will listen to all the event queues by default. You can filter to listen to particular event queue by configuring the filter options in the Subscribe method.

public virtual void InitializeFromPipeline(PipelineArgs args)
{
   var action = new Action<MyEventRemote>(RaiseRemoteEvent);
   Sitecore.Eventing.EventManager.Subscribe<MyEventRemote>(action);
}
private void RaiseRemoteEvent(MyEventRemote myEvent)
{
    Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent("testing:myevent:remote", 
                                     new object[] { myEvent.Param1 });
}

Using above way, CM server can be notified to trigger the action from CD server.
Note: In Sitecore 9 and above, there is defaultEventQueue with respect to role configuration on the environment. Therefore we need to get the database first and then raise the remote events to the database we want to reach as shown above.
<eventQueueProvider role:require="ContentManagement or XMCloud or ContentDelivery">
    <patch:attribute name="defaultEventQueue">web</patch:attribute>
</eventQueueProvider>

More details on the remote event can be found here.
Hope this helps!!!

I do get that. My question is where the details about the event are stored that the CM instance is aware of it

@NutsAndBolts It is stored on the event queue and since the event queue is shared between all the environment, you can pass all necessary parameters when raising the remote event. This parameters then can be retrieved on the CM using args as RemoteEventArgs<LogMessageRemoteEvent> on the event handler.

@NutsAndBolts I have updated the answer above to raise remote events in Sitecore 9 and above. Let me know in case you have any queries.
